# Snowflake views with PowerBI

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have created a fact table by joining three  CRM databases and many dimension tables(approx. 25).  CRM tables get updated everyday and currently the fact table holds 3 million rows. I have enabled CDC to update my fact table with new records. I have to use this fact table for reporting by connecting PowerBI to Snowflake account using direct query.
*PowerBI dashboard will be refreshed hourly to populate new data changes.
So my question is,

1. Is it better to create view, because view gets updated when base table is updated and then query from this view by importing it to PowerBI?
   or
2. Should I go with current CDC+fact table architecture and connect PowerBI to the fact table for reporting.

**(My understanding says PowerBI will execute view in snowflake and fetch the result each time I refresh and in case of table it will just import the latest table from Snowflake.)**

Comment: VIEWs is my recommendation. General rule is in-database is always faster than in-BI tool. Assuming your fact table is in fact a single table and not a star schema of joins, why download 30million record if the aggregation is a smaller number of rows?

Comment: Thank you @Jeffrey for answering. Does this mean if snowflake has tableA and viewA which necessarily depicts the same data when connected to PowerBI behaves differently, which means when I click refresh in PowerBI it will load tableA on whole in PowerBI and incase of viewA just the new rows are added at each refresh click?.

Comment: It's better to perform JOINs in the VIEW instead of having all the data in PowerBI.